# can i make apk used both in mobile and android-TV?

Tags: android, mobile, tablet, television

```
<activity
android:name="yuku.alkitab.base.ac.SplashActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
```

i made changes like this working fine in android tv but not working in Mobile/Tablet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible to publish same app for Android TV and smartphones on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172712/is-possible-to-publish-same-app-for-android-tv-and-smartphones-on-google-play)

Comment: and duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778829/how-to-make-an-apk-can-be-used-both-in-mobile-and-android-tv

Comment: App is install in both device Android TV and Tablet but in tablet app icon is now display